# An elementary puzzle: How old is Rose?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Luna is 34.

Scarlett is 37.

Ray is 88.

Paris is 71.

How old is Rose?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is

> 45.

The theme of the puzzle is

> the periodic table.

*Luna is 34.*

> Element 34: selenium. Selenium and Luna both mean "moon".

*Scarlett is 37.*

> Element 37: rubidium. Rubidium and Scarlett are both related to "red".

*Ray is 88.*

> Element 88: radium, or **ray**-dium.

*Paris is 71.*

> Element 71: lutetium. Paris was formerly called Lutetia.

*How old is Rose?*

> Element 45: rhodium, meaning rose.

Comment: Ray 88 threw me off big time, thinking Ray Charles and 88 piano keys!

Comment: There you go. TBH I was surprised this one lasted even 5 minutes, but like I was saying on meta, they don't all have to be tricky. :) I felt that Ray was the big clue, is that how it worked for you?

Comment: @AE The title immediately told me to look at the periodic table. At first I was trying to spell the names using the standard abbreviations (Lu-Na and so on), but when I realised Ra was 88 already without a Y, I changed tack! It was a fun puzzle :-)

Comment: Glad you liked it! :)

Comment: @rand: Perhaps 45 is what you're missing?  https://www.webelements.com/rhodium/  (I was trying to count letters at first :) lol )

Comment: @Ditto I shadow-edited; it's complete now! :-)

Comment: I'm impressed on fast you got that  :)  well done.